# Get prior row for each element in Where in

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I am working with a PostgreSQL database.

Here the idea :

- An user can play to a game
- Each game can have 1 or more mini-games
- Each mini-game have a result

Here the kind of database :

```
id | user_id | game_id | mini_game_id | result | created_at
-----------------------------------------------------------
70 | 44      | 105     | 22           | 19     | 28/11/2016
69 | 44      | 105     | 20           | 18     | 28/11/2016

68 | 44      | 104     | 22           | 17     | 27/11/2016
67 | 44      | 104     | 21           | 16     | 27/11/2016

66 | 44      | 103     | 22           | 15     | 26/11/2016
65 | 44      | 103     | 21           | 14     | 26/11/2016
64 | 44      | 103     | 20           | 13     | 26/11/2016
```

I want to show at the end of its latest game, beside result of each mini_game, results of the previous same mini_game.

### Result needed :

Example : for `user 44`, at the end of its `game 105`, I want to obtain this data :

```
id | game_id | mini_game_id | second-to-last-result  | date
-----------------------------------------------------------------
68 | 104     | 22           | 17                     | 27/11/2016
64 | 103     | 20           | 13                     | 26/11/2016
```

## What I've tried :

### First try :

```
SELECT mini_game_id, 
    array_agg(result) as results,
    array_agg(created_at) as dates
FROM result
WHERE user_id = 44
    AND game_id != 105 --Exclude latest game
GROUP BY mini_game_id
ORDER BY mini_game_id
```

Result :

```
mini_game_id | results  | dates 
--------------------------------------------------
22           | {17, 15} | {27/11/2016, 26/11/2016}
21           | {16, 14} | {27/11/2016, 26/11/2016}
20           | {13}     | {26/11/2016}
```

Here, the problem is I get every result of each mini_game of each game for an user, and it seems overkill to me, because I can have thousands of results...

### Second try :

```
SELECT id, 
    game_id,
    mini_game_id, 
    result,
    created_at
FROM result
WHERE user_id = 44
    AND game_id != 105 --Exclude latest game
    AND mini_game IN (22, 20) --The two mini-games the user have played in game 105
ORDER BY created_at DESC
LIMIT 1
```

### Result :

```
id | game_id | mini_game_id | result  | created_at
--------------------------------------------------
68 | 104     | 22           | 17      | 27/11/2016
```

### Problem :

Obviously, I get only 1 result. But the idea I had was to `limit 1` on each value inside of the `WHERE IN`

Can you help me understand how I could do this ?
Thanks

Comment: for game 103 why do you pick 20 and 13 and not 22 and 15 like you did with the other.

Comment: Because in game 105, he has played to mini game 22 & 20. So for mini-game 22 : latest result is 17, and mini-game 20 : latest result is 13

Comment: fine, why not return the results of mini game 21 then?

Comment: because he hasn't played mini-game 21 in its latest game 105

Comment: @Citizen is it intended that id = 68 for both of the two rows in section "results needed"?

Comment: Oh, it's a mistake, I correct

Comment: so the rules are -- for each mini game in the current result return the game and mini game of the prior time played?

Comment: Yes, this is it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *
       ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION by user_id ORDER BY created_at DESC) as LatestGame
       ,LAG(result) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, mini_game_id ORDER BY created_at) as SecondToLastResult
    FROM
       Table
)

SELECT
    id
    ,game_id
    ,mini_game_id
    ,result
    ,SecondToLastResult
    ,created_at as Date
FROM
    cte
WHERE
    LatestGame = 1
;
```

Use `DENSE_RANK()` to define latest game and `LAG()` to get the previous result then select where `LatestGame` = 1 from the common table expression [cte]

Here is postgresql's link about window functions: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-window.html

To filter to only 1 user you can do the following because you will no longer need to partition the window functions by user_id:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *
       ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY created_at DESC) as LatestGame
       ,LAG(result) OVER (PARTITION BY mini_game_id ORDER BY created_at) as SecondToLastResult
    FROM
       Table
    WHERE
       user_id = 44
)
```

And just for fun here is how you can do it with out window functions:

```
SELECT
    t.id
    ,t.user_id
    ,t.game_id
    ,t.mini_game_id
    ,t.result
    ,t.created_at
    ,(SELECT result
             FROM
                Table t2
            WHERE
                t.user_id = t2.user_id
                AND t.mini_game_id = t2.mini_game_id
                AND t.created_at > t2.created_at
            ORDER BY
                t2.created_at DESC
            LIMIT 1) as SecondToLastResult
FROM
    Table t
    LEFT JOIN Table t1
    ON t.user_id = t1.user_id
    AND t.created_at < t1.created_at
WHERE
    t1.id IS NULL
    AND t.user_id = 44
```

I would assume window functions will preform better for you though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! I have  a question : Where do I put the conditions like `user_id = 44` ?

Comment: This will do multiple users at a time.  If you want to limit that simply put WHERE user_id = 44 in the common table expression statement

Comment: Wow, it works well :o I don't fully understand what's going on, but I'm going to search. Anyway, thank you !!

Comment: Your welcome, the window functions are very helpful for this like this!  I added a standard query that might give you some insight as to how the window functions work. cheers

Comment: What is the purpose of `t1.id IS NULL` ?

Comment: The join between T and T1 is to identify the latest game.  so it says give me anything in T that doesn't have a record in T1 (itself) that was created later than T.  Truthfully if you game_id can span multiple dates then you would have to use another technique yet but this was just to try and show you what the window functions do in a different manner.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129272/discussion-between-citizen-and-matt).